# Can AdSense crawler view pages that require cookies?

Tags: google-adsense, web-crawlers, cookie

**Details**

I require users to agree to terms and conditions before they can view several pages on my site.
Once they have agreed a cookie is set and they can proceed to the webpage. If a user somehow manages to end up on the webpage without a cookie they will not be able to access the page's content.

**My question(s)**

Is the AdSense crawler able to set the cookie and visit these pages? If yes, how will it know to agree to the TOS? Is there some way to allow it access to the pages even if it couldn't use cookies?

Answer (score 1):

From [Brendon](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/8131/brendon):

> You can [give the Adsense bot credentials](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/161351?hl=en) to log into your website. I suspect that it will track any cookies set, so just set the corresponding cookie on log in. (Not tested).